# Array to replace name of Months with strtotime

Tags: php

Im having a little problem to replace the name of the months.

My Array:

```
$try= array(
       '01'=>'Jan123',
       '02'=>'Fev123',
       '03'=>'Mar123',
       '04'=>'Abr123',
       '05'=>'May123',
       '06'=>'June123',
       '07'=>'July123',
       '08'=>'Agos123',
       '09'=>'Set123',
       '10'=>'Out123',
       '11'=>'Nov123',
       '12'=>'Dez123'
   );
```

The date code:

```
<?php echo $try[date("m Y", strtotime("-10 month"))]; ?>
```

It is showing me blank, no output, any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code output is **12 2017**

```
<?php echo date("m Y", strtotime("-10 month")); ?>
```

and a keys in your array is 01, 02, 03 etc... try to use this code

```
<?php echo $try[date("m", strtotime("-10 month"))]; ?>
```

Comment: I want to display the year to in the second code, the first one I know

Comment: @John `echo $try[date("m", strtotime("-10 month"))] . ' ' . date("Y", strtotime("-10 month"));` ?

Comment: yea, that did the job